# Is 我认为保护环境将为子孙后代保证未来 correct? Does it make sense?

Tags: mandarin, writing-critique

> 我认为保护环境将为子孙后代保证未来

I am trying to say that saving the environment will guarantee a future for future generations. Does it actually mean that or have I made mistakes?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's right. But, it's much better to say, 我认为保护环境就是保护子孙后代的未来.

Answer (score 3):

保证未来 doesn't sound a natural phrasing. Usually, we say 对未来的保证 or 是未来的保证. A more natural one can be 我认为保护环境是对子孙后代未来的保证.

The other way to express this kind of idea in Chinese can be: 为了子孙后代, 我们应该保护环境.

Answer (score 0):

A direct translation of 我认为保护环境将为子孙后代保证未来 will be something close to:

> I believe (我认为) protecting the environment (保护环境) will guarantee a
>   future for offsprings (将为子孙后代保证未来)

While It's understandable, a better way of saying it could be:

> 保护环境将保证下一代/后代的未来

Reason being:
1) 我认为 (I believe) was not in the origin content
2) 子孙后代 vs 下一代 - (your) offsprings vs future generations (which does not necessary related to you by blood)

Answer (score 0):

its a bit unnatural translation, 将and 为 are kinda unnecessary together, not to say the direct translation is not wrong, everyone can understand what you are trying to present, but a native speaker would not phrase it that way. I think rephrasing it as 我认为保护环境会保证子孙后代的未来 will be more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence contains some errors:

1. 认为 means "think" but is followed by 将 "will", which is contradictory
2. 保护环境 "protect the environment" is the subject but 为子孙后代保证未来 "guarantee a future for future generations" treats it as the object
3. 子孙后代 "future generations" should come before 未来 "future" for clearer logic

A correct way to express the meaning could be:

保护环境将为子孙后代保证一个美好的未来。
Protecting the environment will guarantee a bright future for future generations.

或 Or

我们应该保护环境,为子孙后代的未来着想。
We should protect the environment, thinking of the future of future generations.